# What machine learning algorithm should I use for Connect 4?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, neural-network, reinforcement-learning

I have an AI that is good at playing Connect 4 (using minimax). Now I want to use some machine learning algorithm to learn from this AI that I have, and I would like to do that by just letting them play against each other.

What algorithm would be good for this, and how would I train it? If someone could just name a way of doing this I can easily Google it by my self. But right now I don't know what to Google...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely use a neural network to do this. Since it can be hard to find the right amount of input and output nodes and all the weights, I recommend using evolutionary computation techniques (such as a genetic algorithm) to do this.

Hope this helps. Cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Connect Four is a solved game, meaning that there is a strategy that will always allow the player who goes first to win.  You could try to do a machine learning approach, but it would pointless except as an exercise.

You can read how Victor Allis used an expert system to find the winning strategy in his [master's thesis](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.38.2778&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (pdf).

Comment: +1 Excellent point.  There are quite many times that machine learning is inappropriate (not just overkill: just not appropriate), and solved games are such a class of problems.